# Unable to submit a perforce changelist

Tags: perforce

I created a changelist using p4v.  I then tried to submit the changelist via p4 as follows:

```
p4 submit -c 220406
```

The only thing that happens is that the command returns:

```
Change 220406 belongs to client p4.
```

If I enter 'p4 describe 220406' I see the change list as still pending.  Any ideas what I've done wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not currently using the client named "p4".  When you do `p4 describe 220406`, it will show you something like this:

```
Change 220406 by jok4rnaut@p4 on 2014/02/13 12:00:00 *pending*
```

That shows that you were using a client named "p4" when you checked it out.  Now, from the same command prompt, run `p4 info`.  The `Client name:` field will show something different.

In order to check in that changelist, you'll need to be using the "p4" client instead.  You can either submit it by connecting to that workspace in P4V (under Connection/Open Connection) or by changing to the appropriate client root for the "p4" client at a command prompt and running `p4 submit -c 220406`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just completing Mark's answer, to change the root to your existing mapping, you can run these commands:

```
p4 client <nameOfClient>         // opens text editor, either set Stream or mappings
p4 set P4CLIENT=<nameOfClient>   // change variable to your new client  
p4 submit -c 123456              // submit the CL
```

Also some additional useful commands:

```
p4 client -d <nameOfClient>  // deletes the client, so that you can recreate it
p4 set                       // shows current P4 variables (including client etc.)
```